# Play a mp3 in slow/fast

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add to my app the ability to play songs in slow\fast motion.
from a research i done it can be done in two way in iphone :
`OpenAL` and `soundtouch`.

I am looking for something that can help add one of them to my project and to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and just resolved in the following way

If you have any questions I can help you

Install cocos2d http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/download

and with this you can play fast or slow file

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect: (NSString *) pitch (float32) pan (float32) gain (float32)]
```